# Problem using Qt creator with ROS

Tags: ros, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,

I'm trying to use Qt creator to edit my ROS files, I have read a few advices about how to do it. I'll try to explain what I've done and the problems I have concisely:

1. Create a normal ROS pkg using roscreate-pkg (e.g. $roscreate-pkg test roscpp)
2. Given that Qt has some enviromental issues, I've launched Qt creator from command using:

$ sudo -s

$ qtcreator

3. Now I have the welcome page, and I click on Open Project and go to where my project is located in this case: /home/david/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/test and I select the CMakeLists.txt
4. Now I have this image:

[image: Build Location]

5. I cliked on continue (just accepted the default option), and led me here:

[image: Run Cmake]

6. I clicked on Run CMake, and this is what I got:

> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:99 (message):
> [rosbuild] rospack found package "test" at "", but the current directory is
> "/home/david/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/test".  You should double-check your
> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the correct
> precedence order.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
> CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

[rosbuild] Building package test
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- The C compiler identification is GNU

[image: Error]

I don't have a lot of experience with this, I will appreciate an easy-to-understand explanation if possible.

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58430/problem-using-qt-creator-with-ros/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ROS environment is not initialized. This is probably because you start from `sudo -s` which usually puts you in a root shell instead of a user shell.

I would highly recommend not running your GUI as root.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-03-18**:
Thank you! I did initialized my ROS environment ... But when I access root, appeareantly I have to do it again.

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-03-18**:
And the reason I ran Qt as root is because it has an issue when you don't. In this post http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/277821 (you have to translate it to English) explains what happens when you run QtCreator normally. I had the same issue, and by far is the only solution I could find

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-18**:
You are fixing the problem at the wrong end. According the the thread you linked to the problem is still caused by `sudo` or `sudo -s`. Serial ports can be configured to be read as your user (adduser  dialout) and as to the error messages: There should be a solution to that.

**Comment by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on 2013-03-19**:
What would be the right way? I don't really understand the whole idea of environment issues and why using sudo -s is still wrong.
Is the 'adduser  dialout' a command should I execute, and what exactly it does?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-20**:
`sudo -s` will basically run the program as root instead of your user. Besides security issues, your whole user setup isn't there. `adduser <YOUR_USER> dialout` puts you in the group dialout. Usually serialports are accessible then. There also is probably some GUI for user management.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The very simple instructions on the [IDEs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#QtCreator) page should work provided you have set up your ROS environment variables correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1